# Why is only the last output statement executed?

Tags: javascript, output

I'm new to Javascript and I've tried to print multiple Strings but only the last statement is executed,
Code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p id = "demo"></p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Toit"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Noice";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Epic"; 
    </script>
</body>
```

Output:

```
Epic
```

Comment: They're all executed. You overwrite the `innerHTML` value each time.

Comment: Because that's what innerhtml means. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: All three statements are executed.  Each one overwrites the output from the previous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every statement override the previos one.

You should do:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p id = "demo"></p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Toit"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Noice";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Epic"; 
    </script>
</body>
```

By using `+=` you concat the last value, which is exactly the same like doing:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + "Epic";
```